# Smart Way to Get a Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract all the characters located at the right of a specific character (at the SELECT statement):

Example:

Assuming my column has a value of '0/2' (length and values may vary). I need to get only the values after '/'.

The way I´m doing is:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0/2', len('0/2') - CHARINDEX('/', '0/2') )
```

Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: Is "a specific character" a very limited set of characters? Could the split be performed when the data is added instead of when it is queried?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff('0/2', 1, charindex('/', '0/2'), '')
```

It is only two function calls.